# Can we query MySQL DB Table from Oracle DB?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I've a requirement to join two views and find the difference between them, But one view is in MySQL DB and second view is in Oracle DB. I want to run a DB table comparison through Oracle query, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do it but here is the alternative way.

- Export MySQL view and Import it in the Oracle. You need to make a oracle view first to do the import.

Once you have imported your view in oracle. You can easily run the your query to compare both the results.

If you have large data in MySQL view then I will recommend to use Data Loader in Oracle.